# How can I improve my karatsuba Logic so that my code works?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, logic

Can't get my Karatsuba algorithm to work properly. There is an infinite loop in my code. I think the issue starts right after:

```
q = str(int(c) + int(d))
```

because None is the Return value. Why is None being returned?

My investigation so far has led me to conclude that my infinite loop is:

```
pq = Karatsuba(p, q)
```

Rejigging my code but nothing has worked so far.

```py
def Karatsuba( x, y):

    '''
    Input: Two n-digit positive integers. N must be a power of two.

    Output: The product of x and y.
    '''
    if len(x) == 1 and len(y) == 1:

        return int(x) * int(y)

    else:

        split = len(x) // 2

        a = x[:split]
        b = x[split:]
        c = y[:split]
        d = y[split:]

        ac = Karatsuba(a, c)
        bd = Karatsuba(b, d)

        p = str(int(a) + int(b))
        q = str(int(c) + int(d))

        pq = Karatsuba(p, q)

        adbc = pq - ac - bd


        return 10**len(x) * ac + (10**split) * adbc + bd

print(Karatsuba('1234', '5678'))
```

The answer produced should be 7006652

Comment: Hmm... I'm getting 1234 * 5678 = 7006652 (one 5) on my calc. Typo?

Comment: Debugging the code shows that the problem is that a and c are both '' on the third recursion. You need some way of breaking the infinite recursion in case variables are empty.

Comment: `my karatsuba Logic` I don't even recognise *your Karatsuba logic*. Describe what `a = x[:split]` does and what the *Karatsuba multiplication algorithm* would do in that place. Describe what you *think* you are handling in `adbc = pq - ac - bd`. In `10**len(x) * ac` you are handling a full length product using `*`: what have you gained?